# How to control transitions in angular to avoid seeing content loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, transition

When users do click in the button. I'm wondering how it's posible to get the content, render it, and then change the view and do the transition.

For example, in [this website](https://www.doubleclickbygoogle.com/) developed with angular archives that effect.

How is it possible to appear information using transitions when view is rendered? Any example in plunkr or kind of server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default `ng-route` you can define `resolve` properties. The values of these properties have to be resolved (retrieved from server) before the location is changed. This will prevent any view from being displayed before it has been initialised.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vdCVEc?p=preview) for an example.

## Heavy view suggestions

Angular does not have any mechanism builtin that will notify when the DOM has finished rendering. You can however queue certain code to be executed whenever the digest cycle has been finished.

```
// Execute a function at the end of the current digest queue.

$timeout(function() {
  // Do your thing here
  $rootScope.displayView = true;
}, 0);
```

Another approach is to let all the `ng-repeats` inform you when the last entry has been added to the DOM. Note that if you have multiple `ng-repeats` in the view you'll need some kind of mechanism to keep track of them all (promises are your friend).

```
app.directive('postRepeat', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // The ng-repeat directive sets the $last property on the scope to
    // true when processing the last item.
    if (scope.$last){
      $rootScope.displayView = true;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Hmmm...Then if I have to load a lot of data, you recommend me to load it in the resolve function to get it ready for controller renders the view. But...What happens if the view is too heavy (for example: have a lot of ng-repeat)? I mean, is there an event that can be triggered when view is rendered? I suppose not cause everything runs inside a react loop

Comment: @Serginho: You're not loading anymore data than you're already going to load -- resolve will make sure it is loaded before the route is changed so it prevents all that nasty DOM popping behaviour. Note that each route can have its own resolve property (and fires only when the associated route is started).

Comment: @Serginho: If the view itself is still heavy loaded the resolve alone might not be enough. Looping through a zillion ng-repeat items will always be slow since javascript is single threaded. If you really can't segment the view any better (less ng-repeats) you still can hide the view until the DOM build has been completed. But the browser will be frozen for the duration and you'll need to have some code that will notify when the build has been done since angular does not provided anything for this. I'll update the answer with some suggestions.

Comment: Ok, good point. It would be more easy execute an angular callback when scope digest finishes.